# How to left join JSON function in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

Is there anyway to left join JSON function in TypeORM ? I'm trying to do something like below:

```
 .leftJoin(`json_array_elements ((v1.profile -> 'associatedProfiles') :: json)`, 'ap', 'true')
```

But this results in query something like:

```
 LEFT JOIN "json_array_elements  ((v1"."profile -> 'associatedProfiles') :: json)" "ap" ON true
```

and fails with an error:

```
 error: relation "json_array_elements  ((v1.profile -> 'associatedProfiles') :: json)" does not exist
```

It seems TypeORM seems to be strinfifying my left join. Instead what I really need there is

```
 LEFT JOIN  json_array_elements  ((v1.profile -> 'associatedProfiles') :: json) ap ON true
```

Any pointers to how to fix/overcome this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any solution here?

Comment: we also have a problem to left join json_table with the query builder. Any else you find?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using

> .leftJoinAndMapMany()

or

> leftJoinAndMapOne()